# How to add a foreign key into a table using one-to-one relationship in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I am new to ASP.NET, how can I make my `item` table save the `categoryID` which I get from the `category` table? As an example I want the item "Apple mobile phone" to have the category ID which refers to category name which is electronics, I hope you got the picture.

Here is model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class itemTable
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string company { get; set; }
        public string availability { get; set; }

        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public decimal discount { get; set; }
        public decimal tax { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }

        public int categoryid { get; set; }
    }

    public class categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int categoryID { get; set; }

        public string categoryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Context
{
    public class itemTableDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public itemTableDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<itemTable> ItemTables { get; set; }
        public DbSet<categories> categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<itemTable>().ToTable("itemtable");
            modelBuilder.Entity<categories>().ToTable("categories");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried all the possible ways but there is always something wrong, multiple items might be in the same category like phone brand items are all under the "electronics" category

Answer (score 0):

You can configure One-to-One relationship between two entities in such way:

```
    public class ItemTable
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string Availability { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public decimal Discount { get; set; }

        public decimal Tax { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    }

    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("ItemTable")]

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ItemTable ItemTable { get; set; }    

    }
```

Note: Better to use PascalCase in C#